# Handling Numerous OR conditions in Sharepoint 2010 FullTextSQLQuery

Tags: fulltextsqlquery

**I have below requirement**

There are lacks of documents in SP library.These are belongs to staff(170 nationals approx) in my organization.

Users of this application are HRs in my Organization. Set of HRs are handling staff belongs to certain countries.

Say for ex HR "X" is handling some staff coming from 150 countries hence this "X" should see only staff documents from these 150 countries only.

Now challenge here is to restrict rest of 20 countries.I need to mention all 150 countries in where condition OR i need to skip 20 countries in where condition.

But some HRs will access to only 10 countries and shouldn't have access to rest of 160 countries.

Is there any BEST solution for this requirement? Rather than applying OR condition in WHERE. What if users are requesting in future to restrict users based on some other criteria like department which are approx 1000 departments on top of nationality.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks